# Setting up environment variable in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, macos

How can we set environment variables in NodeJs

I have tried this in my terminal

```
NODE_ENV=prod
node index.js
```

and then inside my code when I try to log it (`config.js` file which is imported in index.js and where i configure everything)

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)
```

it gives me `undefined`

Comment: `NODE_ENV=prod node index.js` - it needs to be one command

Comment: @jonrsharpe While the marked answer was able to help me out, would love if you could share your two cents on the updated question

Comment: Why have you updated your question? You already had an answer, and the new version doesn't seem to *ask* anything. If you have a follow up question, ask it separately (after some research).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
export NODE_ENV=prod
```

also you should create a `.env` file and keep all your environments in the same.

In your config file set the default values

```
NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'prod';
```

Comment: @AZ Yap I have environment file, Config file is to take default value if the environment variable isn't provided for the same

Comment: updated answer to set default values in config file.

Comment: You can add it to the bash_profile, so that you don't have to export in each and every new terminals you run the code in.

Comment: @AZ_ Sorry for unmarking your answer, Updated my question, Can you please go through it again?